# Big Data/IoT projects on Ethereum

Tags: dapps, ipfs, iot, enterprise

Can you provide names of Big Data or IoT projects (other than Slock.it) currently running on Ethereum?

I'm especially interested in how Big Data could use it or whether a combination of IPFS and Ethereum could disintermediate this industry.

Comment: Your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's too broad for our Q&A format. If you have more specific questions, edit your post or ask a new question. Please, also refer to the [help center](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/asking) if you have any questions.

Comment: Is it really that broad? I think it's very simple. I'm just looking for the name of any big data projects running on Ethereum. How about the "the top three big data projects on Ethereum"?

Comment: I also want to know that :(